# Alternative to json_last_error() on php 5.2?

Tags: php, json

My json_decode() is failing, but I can't call json_last_error() because that function isn't available in PHP 5.2.6 (introduced in 5.3).

Is there another way for me to get the error message so I can debug my php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a [JSON validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/). Copy your JSON into it and it will tell you where the errors are.

Comment: I tried a different validator which didn't actually find the problem, but the one you linked above was able to catch the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Not much use from within your PHP code (e.g. to log meaningful error messages).  Doesn't really answer the question.